# Update table combining rows based on the same column value

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm having a table called `table` such that:

```
| id | name  | city    |
|----|-------|---------|
| 0  | Rose  | Madrid  |
| 1  | Alex  | Lima    |
| 2  | Rose  | Sidney  |
| 3  | Mario | Glasgow |
```

And I need to **UPDATE** the table so that two rows sharing the same `name` combined into a new one and deleted.

```
| id | name  | city           |
|----|-------|----------------|
| 1  | Alex  | Lima           |
| 3  | Mario | Glasgow        |
| 4  | Rose  | Madrid, Sidney |
```

I don't care if it has to be done in several SQL statements.

So far all I've done is to list the rows that are affected by this.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name IN (
  SELECT name
  FROM table
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is auto increment primary key, you need an `INSERT` and a `DELETE` statement:

```
insert into tablename(name, city)
select name, group_concat(city, ',')
from tablename
group by name
having count(*) > 1;

delete from tablename
where instr(name, ',') = 0 
  and exists (
  select 1 from tablename t
  where t.id <> tablename.id and t.name = tablename.name 
  and ',' || t.city || ',' like '%,' || tablename.city || ',%'  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73HbBcUCrxWA9u5ZPZ4xph/2).
Results:

```
| id  | name  | city          |
| --- | ----- | ------------- |
| 1   | Alex  | Lima          |
| 3   | Mario | Glasgow       |
| 4   | Rose  | Madrid,Sidney |
```